# RDLC / sql returning a blank space instead of showing empty record... please see images

Tags: c#, sql, rdlc

I'm creating a RDLC report from a stored proc and grouping by the EmpNum field, but when sql returns no rows for that EmpNum it doesn't even show on report.

I have tried to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN with a table that contains the the full list of all EmpNum values but I still get the same result

Here is my sql proc

```sql
declare  @FromD as date = '2019-01-01',
           @ToD as date = '2019-01-05'

Select EmployeeData.EmpNum, EmployeeData.PayrollNum, EmployeeData.Name, EmployeeData.Button, 
                       (SELECT Top 1 Description FROM CompanyCodes WHERE Code = EmployeeData.CompanyCode ) AS CompanyCode, 
                       (SELECT Top 1 Description FROM Departments WHERE Code = EmployeeData.Department ) AS Department, 
                       (SELECT Top 1 Description FROM ReportCentres WHERE Code = EmployeeData.ReportCentre ) AS ReportCentre,
                        ClockDate.CalcDate, ClockDate.Day,ClockDate.ID,
                       (SELECT COUNT(*) From Clocking Where IO='In' AND EmpNum = EmployeeData.EmpNum AND CalcDate = ClockDate.CalcDate) as INS,
                       (SELECT COUNT(*) From Clocking Where IO='Out' AND EmpNum = EmployeeData.EmpNum AND CalcDate = ClockDate.CalcDate)as OUTS
                       ,@FromD AS FD, @ToD AS TD
FROM EmployeeData LEFT OUTER JOIN ClockDate 
    ON EmployeeData.EmpNum = ClockDate.EmpNum
WHERE ClockDate.CalcDate BETWEEN @FromD AND @ToD
order by EmployeeData.EmpNum, ClockDate.CalcDate
```

I want the report to still show the EmpNum even if there is no data:

[image: Result I Want]

**[EDIT]**

I have now I fixed the sql with a UNION with the list of EmpNum... Now I have to find a way to hide the empty row on the RDLC to get the above result...

Here is my attempt with the fixed sql :

[image: Current attempt]

And here is my curent sql :

```sql
declare  @FromD as date = '2019-01-01',
           @ToD as date = '2019-01-05'

Select EmployeeData.EmpNum, EmployeeData.PayrollNum, EmployeeData.Name, EmployeeData.Button, 
                       (SELECT Top 1 Description FROM CompanyCodes WHERE Code = EmployeeData.CompanyCode ) AS CompanyCode, 
                       (SELECT Top 1 Description FROM Departments WHERE Code = EmployeeData.Department ) AS Department, 
                       (SELECT Top 1 Description FROM ReportCentres WHERE Code = EmployeeData.ReportCentre ) AS ReportCentre,
                        ClockDate.CalcDate, ClockDate.Day,ClockDate.ID,
                       (SELECT COUNT(*) From Clocking Where IO='In' AND EmpNum = EmployeeData.EmpNum AND CalcDate = ClockDate.CalcDate) as INS,
                       (SELECT COUNT(*) From Clocking Where IO='Out' AND EmpNum = EmployeeData.EmpNum AND CalcDate = ClockDate.CalcDate)as OUTS
                       ,@FromD AS FD, @ToD AS TD
FROM EmployeeData LEFT OUTER JOIN ClockDate 
    ON EmployeeData.EmpNum = ClockDate.EmpNum
WHERE ClockDate.CalcDate BETWEEN @FromD AND @ToD
--order by EmployeeData.EmpNum, ClockDate.CalcDate
Union
Select EmployeeData.EmpNum, EmployeeData.PayrollNum, EmployeeData.Name, EmployeeData.Button,
                       ('') AS CompanyCode, 
                       ('') AS Department, 
                       ('') AS ReportCentre,
                       ('')as CalcDate, ('')as Day,('')as ID,
                       ('') as INS,
                       ('')as OUTS
                       ,@FromD AS FD, @ToD AS TD
From EmployeeData
order by EmployeeData.EmpNum, ClockDate.CalcDate
```

Comment: Why is there a c# tag?

Comment: Does an entry occur if you run query in SQL Server Management Studio?  I think the issue is with the RDLC code and not the query.

Comment: c# tag is because it is a c# win forms application... Maybe there is a fix in the c# form?

Comment: The sql query also returns 0 records... But when it does i would like the result on the report to look like in the photo... But currently it doesn't even show the number with the 0 days

Comment: You only posted SQL and there was no reference in the posting to c#.  Does the SQL Query return any number of the days?  If not then how do you expect the c# to display 0 days?  The c# will only return what the SQL Query returns.  The RDLC may return additional info, but can't tell.  As I said I think this has to be solved in the RDLC.

Comment: How do I solve it in the rdlc when not even the list of EmpNum is returned by the sql? My thoughts on the matter is to union an empty record with only the EmpNum and have the rdlc sort it.... but i also cant get it to do that

Comment: All My Thanks @jdweng , I Just UNION the List of The EmpNum and Now I Get The Desired Result From The SQL... Now I have to find a way to hide the the empty row in the table when a certain column is empty... Wil update the question now...

Comment: Just a summary for other readers 1) Always debug the SQL Query errors in SQL Server Management Studio where the error messages are better. 2) A RDLC file is HTML text.  The query is in the COMMAND_TEXT tag(s) in the RDLC.  The text may have HTML special character (between an ampersand and semicolon) and needs to be replace before running query in SSMS. 3) Fixing issues with RDLC may require changing the query and/or the RDLC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jdweng I figured out what I needed to do...

I made the sql UNION the List of EmpNum and then made the empty rows hide if certain value was an empty string...

Here is my final sql :

```sql
declare  @FromD as date = '2019-01-01',
           @ToD as date = '2019-01-05'

Select EmployeeData.EmpNum, EmployeeData.PayrollNum, EmployeeData.Name, EmployeeData.Button, 
                       (SELECT Top 1 Description FROM CompanyCodes WHERE Code = EmployeeData.CompanyCode ) AS CompanyCode, 
                       (SELECT Top 1 Description FROM Departments WHERE Code = EmployeeData.Department ) AS Department, 
                       (SELECT Top 1 Description FROM ReportCentres WHERE Code = EmployeeData.ReportCentre ) AS ReportCentre,
                        ClockDate.CalcDate, ClockDate.Day,ClockDate.ID,
                       (SELECT COUNT(*) From Clocking Where IO='In' AND EmpNum = EmployeeData.EmpNum AND CalcDate = ClockDate.CalcDate) as INS,
                       (SELECT COUNT(*) From Clocking Where IO='Out' AND EmpNum = EmployeeData.EmpNum AND CalcDate = ClockDate.CalcDate)as OUTS
                       ,@FromD AS FD, @ToD AS TD
FROM EmployeeData LEFT OUTER JOIN ClockDate 
    ON EmployeeData.EmpNum = ClockDate.EmpNum
WHERE ClockDate.CalcDate BETWEEN @FromD AND @ToD
--order by EmployeeData.EmpNum, ClockDate.CalcDate
Union
Select EmployeeData.EmpNum, EmployeeData.PayrollNum, EmployeeData.Name, EmployeeData.Button,
                       ('') AS CompanyCode, 
                       ('') AS Department, 
                       ('') AS ReportCentre,
                       ('')as CalcDate, ('')as Day,('')as ID,
                       ('') as INS,
                       ('')as OUTS
                       ,@FromD AS FD, @ToD AS TD
From EmployeeData
Where EmployeeData.EmpNum not in (Select EmployeeData.EmpNum FROM EmployeeData LEFT OUTER JOIN ClockDate 
                                    ON EmployeeData.EmpNum = ClockDate.EmpNum
                                    WHERE ClockDate.CalcDate BETWEEN @FromD AND @ToD)
order by EmployeeData.EmpNum, ClockDate.CalcDate
```

and here is the row property :

[image: Row Prop]

and here is the result :

[image: Desired Result]

This Was The Link That Helped Me To Hide The Row :
[How to: Apply Conditional Visibility Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicsnav-2009/dd354976(v=nav.60))